# read properties file in multi module project

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, properties, multi-module

Hi I have a project which has two modules with the following structure

`project

    │
    └───Module1
    │        |---abc.jsp
    │

    │
    ├───Module2
        │----src.main.
                  |
                  |---java.
                  |      |---com.xyz.comp
                  |              │----------Action.java
                  |

                  |
                  └───resources
                         |---com.xyz.comp
                                    │   prop.properties`

Now My Module1 has a dependency on war of Module2(Module2 is an independent war file). My problem is that the abc.jsp of Module1 submits to the Action.java of Module2. In which when I try to access prop.properties gives null pointer exception.

```
public static void test(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
   String propfilename = "com/xyz/comp/prop.properties";

    try {
        ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Action.class.getClassLoader();

        InputStream prpoStream= contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(propfilename );


        properties.load(propertiesStream);

        // bunch of other code
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

The propStream is always null because it cannot find the file. Am i giving the path wrong or since this is called from another module the classloader does not have access to this module files?

Comment: Did you add module2 to module1 in order to make it visible to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that resources files (the ones you normally put in `src/main/resources`) wind up in the `WEB-INF/classes` subdirectory of the war-file.

Now, if you try to set your `propfilename` to:

```
String propfilename = "WEB-INF/classes/com/xyz/comp/prop.properties"
```

it will still not work *reliably* (JWS comes to mind) because you are using the classloader from the `Action` class, which is not present in the jar/war you are trying to read from.

> The proper way of doing this is to introduce a third module/dependency
>   where you put your shared resources and have the other modules depend
>   on that.

For JWS (Java Web Start) and other frameworks that use similar classloading strategies, you can use the "Anchor" approach.

**The Anchor approach for classloading**

Since getting hold of the classloader for a given class usually requires you to have loaded the class beforehand, a trick is to put a dummy class in a jar that only contains resources, such as `properties` files. Let's say you have this structure in a jar-file:

```
org/example/properties/a.properties
org/example/properties/b.properties
org/example/properties/c.properties
```

Just throw in a dummy class in the jar, making it look like this:

```
org/example/properties/Anchor.class
org/example/properties/a.properties
org/example/properties/b.properties
org/example/properties/c.properties
```

then, from other code you can now do this and be sure that classloading works as expected:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
String propFile = "org/example/properties/a.properties";

ClassLoader classLoader = Anchor.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream propStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(propFile );

properties.load(propStream);
```

This is a more robust way of doing it.

Comment: i really liked the anchor logic

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();