# How to read properties file from external jar in maven project

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am new to `maven`  and `Java` . I am working on a large codebase which uses the Spring web framework. I may be missing fundamentals but I have done my best to go over all the basics of the project implementation.
For the feature I am building,I have properties files that I had earlier saved in src/main/resources in 
my maven project and  was reading  from my class named `ReaderClass` with this statement

`ReaderClass.class.getResourceasStream("xyz.properties");`

Now I have externalized these files into a separate project and have built a jar out of it. This jar only has the properties files under a folder named resource.
I have added this jar file as an dependency in the IntelliJ IDE  and would like to read the properties files from this jar. Had it been a  .class file I would use an import statement in `ReaderClass` but how would I read properties files?

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

Also, I am not sure if this is a problem but IntelliJ doesn't actually show the jar in the External Libraries Tab but does show my jar in the dependencies tab of the Modules Section in Project Structure. I wanted to make sure this wouldn't affect the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821074/read-properties-file-in-multi-module-project  But if you add the jar as an external library directly in IntelliJ, it might not update the POM. I would recommend going the other way around: update the POM first and the reload it in the IDE.

Comment: I am adding it to the IDE first because I want to test it. When I upload my artifact to the central maven repository we use on nexus.. I'll add the dependency to pom.xml. The solution given in the link you shared talks about adding a class just to use it's class loader. I would prefer not to do that

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Try `ReaderClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xyz.properties");`

Comment: ReaderClass is not in the same jar... the properties files are in a dependency jar..

Comment: Ok, but is there *any* class inside the dependency jar you can use or is it just a jar with *only* data, like a ResourceBundle? This will affect how you need to access it.

Comment: This is a jar with only data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous ways to do this.

Assuming your `xyz.properties` file looks like this:

```
a=b
y=z
mykey=myvalue
```

**Using java.util.ResourceBundle**

If you don't need to pass around the read data as a `Properties` object, this is the easiest way.

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("xyz");
System.out.println("a=" + rb.getString("a"));
```

**Using java.util.Properties**

A bit more work and some boiler-plate, but accomplishes the same thing.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
try (InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xyz.properties")) {
   p.load(is);
}
catch (IOException e) {
   // Handle as appropriately.
}
System.out.println("mykey=" + p.getProperty("mykey"));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring, try

```
@Value("${property.name}")
private String property;
```

to read properties from resources folder.

Comment: I need to load the properties file to a java.util.Properties object